# Jquery countdown onExpiry function

Tags: jquery, timer

I am using jquery countdown.js from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html for my countdown process. Its working fine. The problem is in onExpiry function. 
Please refer the below code,

```
recursivecall = setTimeout(function () {
            get_last_auction();
        }, 10000);

function get_last_auction() {
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_get_lastauction",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) { 

    jQuery('.countbox').countdown({
                    layout: '<b>{d<}{dnn}D:{d>}' + '{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}</b>',
                    timeSeparator: ':',
                    onExpiry: function () { 
                        if(response.val > 10) {
                        //Mycode
                        }
                    },
                    until: response.clock        
                    }); 
    }
  });                       

 }
```

Here i noticed that, though the recursivecall return the different value for "response.clock" for every call, the timer only consider the initial value and starts countdown.

However, i need the current updated value (from my ajax call) for "response.val" within the expiry function for my condition check. But it only consider the initial value(when the timer is set) for "response.val". Is it possible to get the new value inside onExpiry? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, just try to use `complete` instead of `success` because is asynchronous function. Let me know if works now or not.

```
function get_last_auction() {
 var value = null;

 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_get_lastauction",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) { 
        value = response
    },
    complete: function(){
       jQuery('.countbox').countdown({
                    layout: '<b>{d<}{dnn}D:{d>}' + '{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}</b>',
                    timeSeparator: ':',
                    onExpiry: function () { 
                        if(value.val > 10) {
                        //Mycode
                        }
                    },
                    until: value.clock        
     }); 
    }
  });                       

 }
```

**UPDATE**

If **not works** then use `alwaysExpire: true`. Read [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#alwaysExpire).